# Why is this Linq to XML query not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
                new XElement("BookParticipants",
                new XElement("BookParticipant",
                new XAttribute("type", "Author"),
                new XElement("FirstName", "Joe", new XElement("name", 
                    new XElement("noot", "the"),
                    new XElement("iscool", "yes"))),
                new XElement("LastName", "Rattz")),
                new XElement("BookParticipant",
                new XAttribute("type", "Editor"),
                new XElement("FirstName", "Ewan", new XElement("name", 
                    new XElement("noot", "the"),
                    new XElement("iscool", "yes"))),
                new XElement("LastName", "Buckingham"))));


            xDocument.Descendants("BookParticipants").Where(x => (string)x.Element("FirstName") == "Joe").Remove();
            Console.WriteLine(xDocument);

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove the joe element using the where clause. But this is not working. is it possible to delete elements using the where clause?

Comment: What exactly means "this is not working"? Compiler error? Exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: When I run the code the Joe elements are still there. It was not removed. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Hmm... I wasn't aware of that [`Remove` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) before.

The problem is that when you convert an element into a string, it concatenates *all* the descendant text nodes... so the value of the "Joe" element is actually "Joe the yet".

You only want *direct* child text nodes. Frankly it would be easier if the name was in an attribute rather than as content, but it should still be feasible...

Additionally, you're looking for `FirstName` elements directly under `BookParticipants` rather than `BookParticipant`.

This works, although it's not terribly pleasant:

```
xDocument.Descendants("BookParticipants")
         .Elements()
         .Where(x => x.Elements("FirstName")
                      .Nodes()
                      .OfType<XText>()
                      .Any(t => t.Value== "Joe"))
         .Remove();
```

You could change the first bit to

```
xDocument.Descendants("BookParticipant")
         .Where(...)
```

if you want, too.

(Again, if you can use attributes for string values rather than content in elements, that makes life easier.)

Comment: omg. this worked..Do you work for microsoft or something. I am now aware I have alot to learn about linq itself. Thank you -- May i ask which books do you read to learn about linq to xml?

Comment: @Luke101: No, I don't work for MS. I work for Google :) As for reading books... I wrote about LINQ in C# in Depth, so I taught myself with the docs at the time, mostly.